# “Incorrect Signature” Python Twitter

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, signature

I have the following code:

```
import urlparse
import oauth2 as oauth

PROXY_DOMAIN = "twitter1-ewizardii.apigee.com"
consumer_key = '...'
consumer_secret = '...'
consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

oauth_token        = '...'
oauth_token_secret = '...'

token = oauth.Token(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

request_token_url = "https://twitter1-ewizardii.apigee.com/1/account/rate_limit_status.json"
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET", PROXY_DOMAIN)
print resp
print content
```

However I continue to get the error `"error":"Incorrect signature"` this was working earlier, and I tried out solutions people have suggested online, generated new credentials etc, but it doesn't seem to work anymore after working for a week like this.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm wonder if Twitter changed something.  My app was working for months without any changes.  Suddenly I started getting "Incorrect signature" errors yesterday.

Comment: Yea, I just switched myself over to `tweepy` once I got the proxy working on it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have switched to `tweepy` for anyone who finds this question this may be of use to you:

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries

It could have been a glitch on the day I was testing as I didn't go back to trying out the `oauth-python` module since `tweepy` has been working for me. But that link list all the possible libraries available and is a valuable resource if such a problem arises again.